# Cannot drop constraint in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, constraint, merge-replication

When I try to delete a constraint, it gives me the following message:

> "The constraint is used by merge replication for identity management
>   and cannot be dropped directly. Execute sp_changemergearticle
>   @publication, @article, "identityrangemanagementoption", "none" to
>   disable merge identity management, which will also drop the
>   constraint."

However, the replication was deleted from the database earlier by previous users. Now I cannot remove or even modify the constraint. Can you please advice how to remove it now?

Comment: Have you tried `execute sp_changemergearticle @publication, @article, "identityrangemanagementoption", "none"` ?

Comment: Since the replication part of the database was deleted, I don't have publication and article